# DataTable selection doesn't work in Electron

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, electron

first time using electron.
Using the code provided on [datatables.net](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/single.html) the selection doesn't work.
Maybe I'm doing something wrong with electron or other...

Here's the Javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    select: {
        style: 'os',
        blurable: true
    }
} );
} );
```

Here's the HTML code

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Start date</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                        <td>System Architect</td>
                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                        <td>61</td>
                        <td>2011/04/25</td>
                        <td>$320,800</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                        <td>Accountant</td>
                        <td>Tokyo</td>
                        <td>63</td>
                        <td>2011/07/25</td>
                        <td>$170,750</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Donna Snider</td>
                        <td>Customer Support</td>
                        <td>New York</td>
                        <td>27</td>
                        <td>2011/01/25</td>
                        <td>$112,000</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Start date</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: did you included dataTables.select.js file?

Comment: ... and the CSS file (https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.5/css/select.dataTables.min.css)?